# Links inside slick carousel

Tags: slick.js

I'm working with slick.js to build up a carousel: I noticed that links inside slides are clickable even when the slide containing the links is hidden.

Example: I'm able to click on a link (and select it from the inspector) inside slide n.2 even if I'm visualizing slide n.1.

Am I doing something wrong with slick.js? I guess I can use some js workaround (addClass and removeClass) to fix it but I'm wondering if there's something less annoying to solve this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: removing "display: block" from "a" tag.